# Can creatures spawn in caves?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Looking for creatures to get the bonus units for finding them all is quite tedious.  Finding them on land and in water is difficult enough already.

I was wondering, has anyone seen any in a cave at all?  Do they spawn in caves?  I've yet to see any in them, but because of this, I tend to stay away from the caves and focus more on finding creatures elsewhere.  I just don't want to be wasting anymore time looking on land if say the last creature I need is tucked away in a cave.

Comment: I've definitely seen creatures in caves, but I haven't found any that exclusively reside in caves.

Comment: @pushasha I, too, have found creatures in caves and there have been rare cases that I do find cave exclusive creatures as well

Comment: I only found two cave creatures so far. Both did not appear on the surface and both were aggressive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Creatures are able to spawn in caves, sometimes exclusively. Some only come out at night, as well. It varies from planet to planet.

> Certain species may only spawn at night or in particular environments, such as caves, low (or high) altitudes, or in extreme weather conditions.

[Source](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2016/08/18/no-mans-sky-how-to-find-creatures-quickly/)